# C++ strange reference to temporary

Tags: c++

I can't  understand why the following code fails at compile time with "returning reference to temporary". For me singleton can't be a temporary since it's static !?

Thanks

```
#include <memory>

class Parent {
public:
    static const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& get_default_value();
    static const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& get_some_other_value();
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    Child(){}
    static const std::shared_ptr<Child>& singleton;
};

const std::shared_ptr<Child>& singleton = std::make_shared<Child>();

const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& Parent::get_default_value() {
    return singleton;
}

const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& Parent::get_some_other_value() {
    //FILL ME
}
```

[Proof](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=603869b926fe735d11f85fa8e91f8095-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)

Edit: Parent's default value is Child's singleton. (there were some other names before but this was confusing).

Edit 2: Also I wanted to have references to shared_pointers because the default happens a LOT and is a singleton anyways, so one might as well save the space

Edit 3: I want a std::shared_ptr& as a type result since I want the interface to be consistent for the default and for the other values

Edit 4: And for unrelated reasons, the other values need to be shared_ptr<>.

Comment: Why do you need to pass around references to the shared pointer?

Comment: Is your goal to return the `Child` singleton, or the global singleton?

Comment: And why do you want a `shared_ptr` to a singleton?  Normally, I'd expect the getter to return a reference.

Comment: returning the `Child`singleton is the goal. 
Also, I want it to be this way because the parent might have some other values. I'm changing the names to reflect that.

Comment: @James: see Edit 2 above

Comment: @GurgHackpof You still haven't answered the question of why you need to wrap the singleton in a `shared_ptr`. Just have the getter return a reference to the singleton object, no `shared_ptr`s need to be involved.

Comment: @Praetorian: see Edit 3 above. Interface consistency: I compare them and stuff.

Comment: @GurgHackpof The question remains: why a `shared_ptr`, rather than a reference?  I fail to see what `shared_ptr` buys you here (except a bit of extra complexity).

Comment: @JamesKanze: because I want the interface to be consistent between the default value and the non default value which, for absolutely unrelated other reasons, requires to be a shared_ptr.

Comment: @GurgHackpof There's no reason for using a `shared_ptr` in either case.   `shared_ptr` and singleton are really a contradiction: `shared_ptr` implies destruction; a singleton implies no destruction.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I understand what you're saying but shared_ptr is merely an interface, what's behind it, a real shared_ptr or a singleton, is not really the user's concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `Child::singleton` is of type `std::shared_ptr<Child>&` but `get_singleton` returns `std::shared_ptr<Parent>&`. `std::shared_ptr<Child>` can be converted to `std::shared_ptr<Parent>` but not to `std::shared_ptr<Parent>&`, so it has to create a temporary object of type `std::shared_ptr<Parent>` and return a reference to that.

There's usually no reason to return a `shared_ptr` by reference anyway. Just return by value and it will compile.

Answer (score 2):

No singleton is temporary the way you declare it. To declare the static variable do:

```
const std::shared_ptr<Child>& Child::singleton = std::make_shared<Child>();
```

Notice the `Child::`? Also in the function get_singleton use:

```
const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& Parent::get_singleton() {
    return Child::singleton;
}
```

Comment: That can't be the reason. [Proof](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fc247c19cd5e0233e518ec330a3b6448-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the analysis from Dirk that the conversion is the problem, this is a good solution:

```
class Parent {
public:
    static const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& get_singleton();
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    Child(){}
    static const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& singleton;
};

const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& singleton = std::make_shared<Child>();

const std::shared_ptr<Parent>& Parent::get_singleton() {
    return singleton;
}
```

[Proof](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f394b9f1ea5c527add5120cf691a59a5-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94)